# Android: Geocoder getFromLocationName is not giving all results. I am getting only 1 result

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

`List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 5);

            Log.d("size:",""+addressList.size());`

The size always prints 1 . for example: I gave a street address marathahalli as a locationName . I got only 1 value but when i try the same street address in google map i get 10 address . please need some help or any links which can solve my problem .

Answer (score -1):

I have used below code it is working for me, try this code.

```
String address = etEntreAddress.getText().toString();
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();

        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(
                TextUtils.htmlEncode(address), 5);

        if (addresses != null) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(j);
                Log.i("address", "returnedAddress :" + returnedAddress);

            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: I tried your code but still getting only 1 result when i printed using Log.d("size:",""+addresses.size()); .